# jQuery: save and restore part of the dom on escape key

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In a jQuery callback, I would like to store a status of the dom and to restore this status when escape key is pressed :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add callbacks
    // TODO : *** store dom ***

    $( ".editable" ).click(function () {
        // add other callbacks

        $("#add").keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape
                // TODO : *** restore dom ***
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Not clear what you're having trouble with. What do you mean by "status of the dom"? Can you give an example of the HTML that gets "stored", how that HTML changes, and what "restoring" it would do?

Comment: Which section of the HTML are you trying to save and restore?

Comment: @maxedison, Eric: I wanted to restore the entire dom with its behavior (callbacks) as it was before the update with jQuery. We solved the problem by reloading the page with window.location.href=pageUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by reloading the page with window.location.href="url" :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add callbacks

    $( ".editable" ).click(function () {
        // add other callbacks

        $("#add").keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape
                window.location.href="thisPageUrl";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So we don't need to store any status. Just rely on http request.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add callbacks
    var original = $(".editable").html();

    $(".editable").click(function () {
        // add other callbacks

        $("#add").keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape
                $(".editable").html(original);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Which element are you trying to save and restore?

Comment: This doesn't preserve bound JS events.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the HTML with $('html').html() and then insert that back in after ESC.